# Accessing Splunk Cloud Rest API

Tags: splunk

Has anyone had any experience accessing custom rest APIs in Splunk Cloud?

I have created a custom API with a python handler but have not been able to test this in Splunk Cloud as the free development environment does not allow this functionality.

Locally (in Splunk Enterprise) the endpoint is available at https://localhost:8089/services/[endpointName], should this be the case when uploading to splunk cloud with localhost replaced with the domain that we are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact Splunk support to have them enable API access to your stack.  Since free/trial accounts don't have access to support, you also can't use the API.